# Sending the HttpsException to the Android app within request.post callback, in https.onCall Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I've defined a `https.onCall` Cloud Function in which I call `request.post` (where `request = require('request')`). In the callback, `function(error, response, body)`, I want to detect two use cases: a) is there any error? If yes, I must send to the Android app a `functions.https.HttpsError` ; b) is there no error at all ? If yes, I must send to the Android app a JSON object containing a success message.

The code I've written is shown below. It doesn't work: the Android doesn't execute the block below the condition `if(!task.isSuccessful())` (see part "Android app side code")

```
/**
 * Verifies a Recaptcha filled by the user in his Android app.
 * 1. Success: returns the JSON response
 * 2. Failure: throws the error
 **/
exports.verifyRecaptcha = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const user_response_token = data.userResponseToken;
    if(user_response_token === null || user_response_token === '') {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with an adequat user response token.');
    }

    const remote_url = 'https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';  // Original value: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';  #  Moises' value: https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
    const secret = '<Secret_Key>';
    request2.post({url: remote_url, form:{secret: secret, response: user_response_token}}, function(error, response, body) {
        if(error) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(error);
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error);
        }

        if(response.statusCode !== 200) {
            console.log("error status code");
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Something went wrong. Status code: ' + response.statusCode + '.');
        }

        body_in_json = JSON.parse(body);
        if(!body_in_json.success) {
            console.log("error body");
            console.log(body);
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Unable to verify this captcha.');
        }

        return {code: 'Success', message: 'You are actually a human (this msg is for test purposes).'};
    });
});
```

## Important note: these 4 lines work

The four first lines re-written below does actually work (if I add the condition `1 === 1`, the exception is really thrown to the Android app, which actually catches it, it works perfectly). So the problem is directly bound to the way I've implemented the `request.post` callback.

```
const user_response_token = data.userResponseToken;
if(user_response_token === null || user_response_token === '') {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with an adequat user response token.');
}
```

## What I've tried to do

1. Returning the promise of `request.post` but I know that this promise shouldn't be returned, by the way it makes the Cloud Function crash with something like "maximum deepth of call stack reached", normal.
2. Returning the `functions.https.HttpsError` instead of throwing them, but it didn't solve the problem

## Android app side code

```
final SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse response = task.getResult();
assert response != null;
final String userResponseToken = response.getTokenResult();
if (!userResponseToken.isEmpty()) {
    final HashMap<String, String> the_data = new HashMap<>();
    the_data.put("userResponseToken", userResponseToken);
    FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
            .getHttpsCallable("verifyRecaptcha")
            .call(the_data)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void then(@NonNull final Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) {
                    if(context.isDestroyed() || context.isFinishing()) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Exception e = task.getException();
                        if (e instanceof FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                            FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
                            System.out.println(ffe.getMessage());
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    callback.onAsking();
                    return null;
                }
            });
} else {
    callback.onFailureUserResponseTokenIsEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Your function is not returning anything to the caller.  It needs to return something from the top-level of the function.  The return statement you have inside the callback function is not getting sent to the caller, it's just being returned from that callback.  You should instead return a promise that resolves with the data to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` supports callback interfaces natively but does not return a promise, which is what you must do within a Cloud Function when you deal with asynchronous operations like the call to an API (Watch this official video series for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/ (in particular the 3 videos titled "Learn JavaScript Promises").

You could therefore use [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise) and the  `rp()` method which "returns a regular Promises/A+ compliant promise" and then do something like:

```
  exports.verifyRecaptcha = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

      const user_response_token = data.userResponseToken;
      if(user_response_token === null || user_response_token === '') {
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with an adequat user response token.');
      }

      const remote_url = 'https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';

   // Original value: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';  #  Moises' value: https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
      const secret = '<Secret_Key>';

      var options = {
          method: 'POST',
          uri: remote_url,
          body: {secret: secret, response: user_response_token},
          json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
      };



      return rp(options)
        .then(parsedBody => {
            return {code: 'Success', message: 'You are actually a human (this msg is for test purposes).'};
        })
        .catch(error => {
             throw new functions.https.HttpsError('....', error);
             //To enrich if necessary with differnt cases
        });

  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i've just a question. Why to throw an HTTP-level error (an HttpsError) in the `catch`, while returning an application-level code (a JSON object containing a code) in the `then`?

Comment: The `catch()` method returns a Promise and deals with rejected cases only (i.e. **if an exception is thrown** in the `then` block), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch. Firebase doc advises to throw an `functions.https.HttpsError` in the catch block, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors

Comment: Thanks! I've upvoted your comment. I didn't find the expectable exceptions that would be catchable (cf. your comment "//To enrich if necessary with differnt cases"). I've read this doc but indeed I didn't find useful information about it (note that the error codes that are shown are not exceptions, they actually are part of the server's answer): https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify . My question is: do you know where I can find the list of the different cases of exception?